# How to access tag in SWT Dialog for Mac OS

Tags: macos, dialog, tags, swt

I'm developing Mac OS Environment.

I am writing an SWT Dialog, but when I open the dialog, I cannot access the tags supported by Mac.
How do I keep a list of files when I click a tag after opening a dialog with SWT?

[image]

Comment: SWT does not support that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWT does not support Mac OS Tag access.